# How to install CMake & DLIB on AWS EB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ebs, aws-elb

I am moving my project (minimal face recognition API) to Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk.
I am having issues with `requirements.txt`.
I want to install `DLIB` which in turn depends upon `CMake`.
I've included `CMake` in my `requirements.txt` but while installing `DLIB` it says CMake should be installed!

Here are last few logs:

```
    ----------------------------------------
    Failed building wheel for dlib
    Running setup.py clean for dlib
  Failed to build dlib
  Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib: started
      Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
      Complete output from command /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-T7rn2s/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-JqBH6P/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/python/run/venv/include/site/python2.7/dlib:
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-T7rn2s/dlib/setup.py", line 257, in <module>
          'Topic :: Software Development',
        File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 604, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-T7rn2s/dlib/setup.py", line 127, in run
          cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-T7rn2s/dlib/setup.py", line 123, in get_cmake_version
          "\n*******************************************************************\n")
      RuntimeError:
      *******************************************************************
       CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
      *******************************************************************
```

Here's my requirements.txt:

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask_Cors==3.0.6
numpy==1.11.0
imutils==0.4.6
six==1.11.0
setuptools==39.1.0
enum34==1.1.6
futures==3.2.0
funcsigs==1.0.2
pbr==4.2.0
markdown==2.6.11
protobuf==3.6.1
werkzeug==0.14.1
wheel==0.31.1
absl-py==0.4.1
astor==0.7.1
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
gast==0.2.0
grpcio==1.15.0
mock==2.0.0
tensorboard==1.9.0
termcolor==1.1.0
tensorflow==1.9.0
Pillow==5.2.0
opencv_contrib_python==3.4.2.17
lxml==4.2.5
h5py==2.8.0
Cython==0.28.5
cmake==3.12.0
dlib==19.15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Insall Cmake using yum in elastic beanstalk

```
packages:
  yum:
    libusb: []
    libusb-devel: []
    cmake: []
```